# Playing audio in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-audiomanager

In My Application im using following code to play audio file

```
Uri data = Uri.parse("file:/" + songnameandpath);
                intent.setDataAndType(data, "audio/*");

                            PackageManager packageManager = getActivity()
                                    .getPackageManager();
                            List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager
                                    .queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
                            boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;




                            if (isIntentSafe) {
                                startActivity(intent);
```

so now when user clicks on back button audio get stopped what if i want to play audio even if the user presses back button on activity and moreover it has to play in background exactly how audio will in mobiles.

Sample code will helps me a lot.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You should use `Uri.parse("file://" + ...` or `Uri.fromFile(java.io.File)` the schema has two `//` so it's `file:///sdcard/music.mp3` - the other version works by accident

Comment: its playing audio file but its get stopped when once presses back button. I want to audio has to start in notification bar how default audio file will play

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried working with media player?

here is the code that worked for me,  just delete the on pause/destroy methods or redefine them and you will have sound playing even when the user presses back..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mp= MediaPlayer.create (this, R.raw.sound); // sound is for example your mp3 song
        mp.start ();      
    }

    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mp.release();
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mp.pause();
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mp.start();
    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

}
```

**update**

The   **MediaPlayer** will continue playing file even after the activity is finished unless you explicitly stop it by stop function

Comment: thanks for your answer but i need a code to initiate default media player in mobile more ever it has to start playing in status/notification bar